# SSRS Can run large report locally, but get blank page running from remote host

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an SSRS 2012 report that takes 5 minutes to render.

When I run it locally in the Report Manager (`http://localhost/Reports/`) it renders just fine after 5 minutes.

When I run it remotely in the same Report Manager (`http://server_name/Reports/`) it will show "Loading..." for about 10 minutes, then "Loading..." disappears and the report never shows up.

When running the same report with shorter time interval parameters, it takes 2 minutes to render, and renders just fine both locally and remotely.

UPDATE: Remote rendering works in Chrome, Firefox, but not in IE.

Answer (score 0):

add this in config file:-

```
<appSettings>
    <!-- default is 1000 -->
    <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="2000" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: This may answer the question, but would be more helpful with [evidence](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/7693/206345) to support it, for example a short program, or a link to documentation or specifications.

Comment: Also, can you elaborate?  Where is this config file?  Do we need to create?